# Check all bits set/unset

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm new to Verilog, and I'm taking my first steps with FPGA "programming".
I have a parametrized module definition similar to that:

```
module foobar #(
    parameter BITS = 4
) (...);

   reg[BITS - 1:0] counter = 0;
   ...
   if (counter == |) begin
      ...
   end
   ...
endmodule
```

and want to test at `|` whether all bits of `counter` are set (or unset). How to achieve that?  Without parametrization, it would be easy by specifying, e.g. `4'b1111` (or `4'b0000`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the replicated concatenation operator.  Check if all bits set:

```
   if (counter == {BITS{1'b1}}) begin
```

Check if all bits cleared:

```
   if (counter == {BITS{1'b0}}) begin
```

Alternately, with SystemVerilog features enabled:

```
   if (counter == '1) begin // All set
   if (counter == '0) begin // All cleared
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this. Here are just a few of them

```
// all bits set
if (&counter == 1'b1) // reduction and(&) operator - Verilog
if (counter  == '1)   // fill literal '1
if (~counter == 0)   // bitwise negation 

// all bits clear
if (|counter == 1'b0) // reduction or(|) operator - Verilog
if (counter  == '0)   // fill literal '0
if ($countones(counter) == 0) // system function
```